# Error when installing docker on Xubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa

Tags: linux, terminal, docker, xubuntu

I tried to install docker with this command,

```bash
sudo apt install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

And it returns this error:

```
the following packages have unmet dependencies: containerd.io : Depends: libseccomp2 (>= 2.5.0) but 2.4.3-lubuntu3.20.3 is to be installed
```

---

Docker desktop failed to install too.

Does anyone know the reason for this error or any work around on how to get docker installed? Thank you.

Comment: I thought you're running xubuntu? why the lubuntu packages?

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers. See [the relevant help-center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it to work by re-installing my linux OS and running:

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

And then installing docker desktop by the .deb installer.

Comment: This is a decent answer, but reinstalling the Linux OS side-steps the issue that the asker was running into. It's akin to saying "having engine problems with your car? buy a new car!". I think a better solution would address the dependency issue mentioned in the question. This can sometimes be resolved by running `sudo apt update` to get an updated package list. Sometimes, multiple package versions are available, so you may need to select the correct one by doing `sudo apt install package=version`. Use `apt-cache show package` to get a list of available package versions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Usually, to install `docker`, all you need to do is:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install docker.io
```

The rest are dependencies.

And if you need `docker desktop`:

```
wget 'https://desktop.docker.com/linux/main/amd64/docker-desktop-4.23.0-amd64.deb'
apt install ./docker-desktop-4.23.0-amd64.deb
```

See https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/ubuntu/